# Setting value for a drop down list through TypeScript on Angular 2 component?

Tags: angular

I have a component with a form. I can preset values for text values for the form like this:

```
private formBuilder: FormBuilder;
private customer: Customer;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newCustomerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName = new FormControl(this.customer.firstName, []),
        //this.customer.firstName = "John"
        ...
    })
}
```

Can I use this pattern to set drop down list values?

Comment: Yes you can do that. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you can only set the selected value, especially the selected key. To fill the "select"-control with "options", you need to do this with an *ngFor-Directive.

Comment: I have no issues filling the DDL with options using ngFor. Just looking for a way to preselect an option from that